# npm not installed latest version of package even after using caret(^)

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

I have added a package(X) as follows in package.json file

> package(X): "^5.0.0"

now the latest version of package(X) is 5.0.1. According to my understanding this should install 5.0.1 but it installs version 5.0.0 itself.

Now I have multiple angular projects which are using package(X) and each of them have the same setup. What surprises me is that it works absolutely fine i.e installs version 5.0.1 in some projects and does not in some projects

Here is the info about package(x)

[npm library info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/369ea.png)

Comment: Delete packagelock and try again? And install with @latest might also help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does depend on other packages' dependencies.
If there is a package that requires X to be exactly 5.0.0, then it will install 5.0.0 as it will satisfy ^5.0.0.
If there isn't one, then it will install whichever latest that will satisfy ^5.0.0 which is 5.0.1 in this case.

Comment: I cross checked and in my case I don't think any package depends on version 5.0.0 of package(X) can there be any other reason

Comment: Have you checked lock file generated? It should tell you clearly as it's not easy to check all co-dependencies manually.

Comment: yes checked the package-lock.json and found no other packages had any dependency on package(x)

Comment: So my guess as to why you posted this question is to find out how npm package version resolution work and if what you’re experiencing is a bug on npm. Now since I don’t know the the history of the package(X) version releases in relation to repos you said are installing not the latest version, I would suggest that you create, say 10 new repos and install package(X) and only package(X) on each. If you see any repo that installs v5.0.0 instead of v5.0.1 (assuming it’s still the latest), I think you may have found a bug on npm.

Comment: But if you're looking for a solution to a specific problem, I don't think it's specified in the question so do update the question and I'll try to answer if it's something I can help you with.

Comment: Yeah I'm actually looking for a specific solution. Here package(X) is a custom package built by us. I have added more info about the package in the question

Comment: So testing it with new repo doesn't help you at all as you just want to make sure new version is installed. Simple solution: So unless you have need to have it "^5.0.0", you want to set to specific version like "5.0.1". We do this for our own packages in Github. Well, we still keep "^" in front of the version but we do update version number to force npm/yarn to install the that version. There's another method of updating the lock file itself but I wouldn't go there except to control 3rd-party package nested dependency issue.

Comment: yeah that is one solution but if we publish a newer version of the library then all the projects using package(x) needs to updated again and deployed right..... so I just want to keep that as a last resort

Comment: Now, I understrand what you're trying to do. Actually, there's no way to force installing newer version unless you remove lock file altogether (it's re-created every time you run npm install/yarn). And that will have a side effect of doing the same for other 3rd-party packages. The lock file is what guarantees that everyone is running same version of all packages. "^" or "~" only has an affect when installing packages without the lock file.

Comment: Actually, instead of updating version on the package.json, just do `npm i package(X)`/`yarn add package(X)` on each repo and it will try to install the latest version. This should be quicker than modifying package.json and do npm i/yarn.

Comment: as mike and ethan pointed out deleting both node_modules and package-lock.json did the trick for me